# Clear data in div via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have script with AJAX call

Here is code

```
<script>
$('#save_quest').click(function () {
    $(".count").html("");
    email_update();
});
function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
            // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var arrow  = '@Url.Content("~/Images/plus_plus.png")';
                var edit = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")';
                var questionHtml = '<div class = "title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:10px;">'
                    +
                    '<img class="click" src="'
                    + arrow
                    + '">' +
                    '<span class="test">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="testclass" readonly value="' +
                    result[i].Quest + '">' +'<a style="margin-left:25px;">'+'<img src=">'+ edit+'">' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".count").append(questionHtml);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to clear div and then show data to it, but `$(".count").html("");` didn't clear html.

Where is my problem?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Eugene, you should debug more, such as putting a breakpoint after `.html("")` to make sure that is where your problem really is... then debug in the ajax callback or view the network activity to see if the response is what you are expecting.

Comment: @smerny cool......

Comment: do console.log(questionHtml) before   $(".count").append(questionHtml);

Comment: are you sure not same same values are appended after ajax call are you receiving different values in ajax call?

Comment: You are mis-diagnosing the problem. Unfortunately you haven't provided enough information for us to find the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following:

```
$(".count").empty();
```

Comment: this and `.html("")` are effectively the same thing